# Put an array with foreach inside another array

Tags: php, arrays

I've just achieved a code where I make an array with `foreach` and in the same code I already have an existing array. What I want to do is to make only one array with those two results. Here is my code for the first array :

```
$sql = "SELECT photoprofile,username from photo WHERE username IN ('somearray')";


$resol = array();
$resulol = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$photos = mysqli_fetch_all($resulol, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$photos = array_column($photos, "photoprofile", "username");
foreach ( $restest as $user ) {
  if ( isset($photos[$user])) {
     $res[] = $photos[$user];
 }
 else    {
     $res[] = '';
 };
}
```

And here is my second array :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
  array_push($res2, array(
  "name"=>$row['name'],
  "publisher"=>$row['username'],
  "image"=>$row['photo'],
 )
);}
```

If you have any tips, any comment or even a question (if I wasn't clear enough for you), just ask me ! Thanks !

Edit : 
What I want to make is an array of this type :

> [{"name":"usera","publisher":"Jeana","image":"urla",""photouser","url2a"},{"name":"userb","publisher":"Jeanb","image":"urlb","photouser","url2b"}]

Comment: You need to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This one lacks example of input data and expected output

Comment: I have done some edits

Comment: What is an example of the $user variable in the first loop? And what does $photos[$user] return?

Comment: I returns a simple array as you can see with $res[]

Comment: If both arrays share the same structure you might want to look into existing array_merge function http://php.net/array_merge.

Comment: I meant what values does it return? You need a key on which to join the arrays. For example does $user in loop 1 = $row['name'] in loop 2? Pls show what data is in the $user and $photos['user'] variables.

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: Both array are not the same structure

Comment: How do you know which photouser belongs to which user?

Comment: i know it because on my $sql line, I check the result of photoprofile by SELECTING them in (array), this array is a list of username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieve what I wanted to do, by using a replacement technic : 
With the foreach loop, I've created an array with the parameter `profilepic`, on the other array, I've created another parameter with a default value, then I replaced it.
My code : First my foreach loop :

```
foreach ( $restest as $user ) {
  if ( isset($photos[$user])) {
     array_push($res1, array(
     "profilepic"=>$photos[$user]));
 }
 else    {
   array_push($res1, array(
   "profilepic"=>'defaultvalue'));;
 };
}
```

and then I changed :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
  array_push($res2, array(
  "name"=>$row['name'],
  "publisher"=>$row['username'],
  "image"=>$row['photo'],
  "profilepic"=>'defaultvalue'
 )
);}
```

And finally I replaced it by :

```
$res = array_replace_recursive($res2,$res1);
```

So my final array with `echo json_encode($res)` is:

> [{"name":"usera","publisher":"Jeana","image":"urla",""profilepic","url2a"},{"name":"userb","publisher":"Jeanb","image":"urlb","profilepic","defaultvalue"}]

Comment: Just a note; though your solution works, it is rigid, meaning that the two arrays must match and be in the same order otherwise you may end up with a mis-matched array. If you decide to change the behavior in the future where the arrays are not equal in count, expect the functionality to break. Also, you can check off your answer as marked correct with the green check mark, just click the transparent check beside your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ! I think this solution will work for me because my two arrays match and will match for ever. I will check my answer as correct when I will be able to do it (it tells me 2 days remaining before I can do it)

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right, I forgot about that 2-day delay...cheers

Comment: No problem !  I'll do it, if you like my post please upvote it (because I tried my best to be clear and many people downvoted it which is kind of bad for my since I just begin in this forum). Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the key you have in the first portion:

```
$sql = "SELECT photoprofile,username from photo WHERE username IN ('somearray')";
$resol = array();
$resulol = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$photos = mysqli_fetch_all($resulol, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$photos = array_column($photos, "photoprofile", "username");
# Set the username--vvvevvvvv
foreach($restest as $username => $user) {
    # Store the username as the key here for reference later
    $res[$username] = (isset($photos[$user]))? $photos[$user] : '';
}
```

In this array, reference the username from the other array:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){    
    $res2[] = array(
        "name"=>$row['name'],
        "publisher"=>$row['username'],
        "image"=>$row['photo'],
        # Using the username as the key name, see if it $res has a saved value
        "photouser" => (isset($res[$row['username']]))? $res[$row['username']] : false
    );
}
```